# Erro no WHMCS ao utilizar boleto fácil

Tags: php

estou usando o módulo do boleto fácil para o whmcs
ele esta retornando o seguinte erro

```
array(2) { ["result"]=> string(5) "error" ["message"]=> string(51) "Admin User var is required if no admin is logged in" }
```

meu cod que gera este erro é este

```
function cpfcnpj($busca,$id){
        $dados['clientid'] = $id;
        $dados['stats'] = true;
        $dados['responsetype'] = 'xml';

        $cliente = localAPI('getclientsdetails',$dados);
        var_dump($cliente);
        foreach ($cliente['client']['customfields'] as $pos=>$val)
            if (in_array($busca, $val)) {
                $campo = $pos;
            break;
        }
        $valor = $cliente['client']['customfields'][$campo]['value'];

        return $valor;
    }
```

onde fica esse `localAPI` ? ou como deveria fazer para resolver?

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver 
o parametro `localAPI` requisita um usuario de admin

entao alterando para

```
 $cliente = localAPI('getclientsdetails',$dados,'adm');
```

onde adm é meu usuário administrativo do whmcs o problema foi resolvido.